# Git command in a PowerShell task in an Azure yaml pipeline

Tags: azure, powershell, devops

Anyone with experience with PowerShell scripts in an Azure pipeline? Running into an issue where the command

```
steps:
- checkout: self
  persistCredentials: true 

- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: "Do some PowerShelling"
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      $pattern = "\d+.\d+.\d+"
      $s = (git branch -r | Select-String "origin\/release\/name\-[0-9.]+")
      $versions = [regex]::Matches($s, $pattern).Value
```

Works as intended locally, the `$s` variable contains the results of the git command, but in the Azure DevOps task it does not evaluate the git command. The task fails because the `$s` is null.

Anyone know what I am doing wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that PowerShell in Azure YAML can run the git function perfectly fine, the problem was that `git branch -r` didn't return any results when executed in Azure. Switch it out with `git ls-remote` did the job.